# EPUB Page number values

Tags: epub

According to the epub spec a page number can be defined as:

```
<p>
   …
   <span epub:type="pagebreak" id="page23">23</span>
   …
</p>
```

And in the page-list:

```
<nav epub:type="page-list">
  <ol>
    …
    <li><a href="georgia.xhtml#page752">752</a></li>
    …
  </ol>
</nav>
```

Does the value of the page number need to be a integer value? In otherwords, will the following be valid:

```
<p>
   …
   <span epub:type="pagebreak" id="pagei">i</span>
   …
</p>
```

Will this cause issues on any of the popular readers?

Comment: Amazingly, neither the latest Kindle Formatting Guide or ibooks asset guide mention any directions here. So I think you can assume that support is either epxerimental or nonexistent.

Answer (score 1):

Support for actual page numbers is practically non-existent on almost all e-readers. You've tagged this epub3—I'll point out that epub3 support is *also* practically non-existent...

I don't think using non-integer values is going to cause issues on many readers, because I doubt many of them will care. I also don't think many of them will break on the page, unless you have explicit css to force a page break.